# gtk: how to use g_signal_emit properly?

Tags: r, gtk

Happy new year everybody,

I would like to understand how to use g_signal_emit properly. I have a gtk_event_box and I want to cause it to emit a enter_notify_event when I want it to. What I tried (R GTK binding code):

```
on_enter = function(...){TRUE}

w = gtkWindow()
ebx = gtkEventBox()
gtkContainerAdd(w, ebx)
gtkWidgetAddEvents(ebx, GdkEventMask["enter-notify-mask"])
gSignalConnect(ebx, "enter-notify-event", on_enter)
```

What arguments to I have to pass to g_signal_emit now? My naive approach does not work..

```
gSignalEmit(ebx, "enter-notify-event")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: okay, found out myself. The answer is simple. Just modify the last function call:     `gSignalEmit(ebx, "enter-notify-event", NULL)`

Comment: It might be useful if you add the answer and later you approve it.  In that way, it would be documented the question and the answer.  Otherwise, it would look like there is no answer for your question. [Please, check the comments in the Etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @gpoo's comment I post my solution as a separate answer here.
The answer is simple: You just have to modify the last function call to:

```
gSignalEmit(ebx, "enter-notify-event", NULL)
```